# leftnavigation animation doesnt fold in correcly

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you take a look at : http://www.wearewebstars.dk/frontend/Borneunivers/boerneunivers.html
And start clicking around in the left navigation, you will notice that sometimes when clicking a link in the navigation, It doensnt collapse the link you were coming from - Any ideas?
The script i have for it is:

```
//Left navigation Animation
            $(".left-navigation ul li").hover(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('current')){

                } else {
                    $(this).animate({'width': '95%'}, 100, function() {
                        $(this).find("span.nav-text").delay(100).css("display", "inline-block");
                    });
                }
            }, function(){  
                if($(this).hasClass('current')){

                } else {
                    $(this).animate({'width': '35px'}, 0, function() {
                        $(this).find("span.nav-text").css("display", "none");
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: The issue seems to happen when you click a new navigation item not when you hover. Please provide relevant code snippet for when a navigation item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should `.stop()` the animation queues in order to interrupt additional animations to build up:

http://jsbin.com/oxisal/1/

```
$(".left-navigation ul li:not(.current)").hover(function( e ){

     var mEnt = e.type=="mouseenter"; // boolean true/false

     $(this).stop().animate({width: mEnt?'95%':35}, mEnt?100:0, function() {
         $(this).find("span.nav-text").css({
             display: mEnt? "inline-block" : "none"
         });
     });

});
```

you should `.stop()` also on click

Answer (score 0):

I think that they should check the class 'current' also in the .click event and not just in the .hover event, otherwise also if you go in another page the old menu button of the prev. page remains selected until you hover it